# Проверить существование изображения

Tags: header, gd, php

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как проверить существование файла изображения. Пробую [так](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50846/):

```
<?
// файл, который мы проверяем
$url = "http://url.to/img.jpg";
$Headers = @get_headers($url);
// проверяем ли ответ от сервера с кодом 200 - ОК
if(strpos('200', $Headers[0])) {
echo "Файл существует";
} else {
echo "Файл не найден";
}
?>
```

Но мне приходит 404!!! Изображение отдается GD php. Какие варианты проверки существования изображения есть еще?

Comment: @Gorbusha, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Зачем на 200? Делайте проще!

```
$url = "http://url.to/img.jpg";
$headers = @get_headers($url);
if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: я имею ввиду, что при попытке проверить наличие файла по заголовку не получается он постоянно пишет 404, изображение генерируется GD

Comment: Тогда используйте curl, шлите заголовки, если изображение генерируется динамически.